# Magento 2: Change message location

Tags: magento2, messages

In the Login page, I want to show a message in below Login Button instead of page top.

How to change Login page error message position in below Login Button in Magento 2.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Did you get my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Create **customer_account_login.xml** in your theme and move message block to **customer.login.container**

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Customer/layout/customer_account_login.xml

**customer_account_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="messages" destination="customer.login.container"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I want to show only error msg in below login button