# How to change message position in magento 2

Tags: magento2, login

I want to show a message like error or success in below Login Button instead of page top in login page.

How to change message position in below Login Button in Magento 2?

Comment: are u need only login page right?

Answer (score 1):

Create **customer_account_login.xml** in your theme and move message block to **customer.login.container**

```
<move element="messages" destination="customer.login.container"/>
```

**Full answer here:** [Magento 2: Change message location](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177528/magento-2-change-message-location/177561#177561)