# Magento 2 notifciation message issue

Tags: magento2, messages, success-message, notification

My error/success messages in **Magento** has latency, means it appears when I go to the next page. i.e, When I add a product to cart, instead of showing a `success notification` message on the refresh of the page, it shows nothing and it appears when I browse to any other page next, then I see 
*`Your product has been added to cart`* message.
Sometimes this happens all over the page and sometimes not. Random behavior

How to fix that, and move the notification message to the top instead of the bottom for all pages?

Something like this below header. It should for all pages, so instead of writing to `<move>` container in respective XML, I want to move it at the top for all pages.

[image]

Comment: did it happen when you use the default Magento theme?

Comment: @magefms I am using Amely theme

Answer (score 1):

On your **ajax add to cart success function** you need to add following lines

```
//Display error if found after jquery
var messages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
if (!_.isEmpty(messages)) {
    customerData.set('messages', {messages: messages});
    $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
}
```

I was facing almost same issue and fixed by this small script

And to move notification messages top of the page, please follow this link, this will help you move messages anywhere in your code

> [Magento 2: Change message location](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177528/magento-2-change-message-location)

Comment: @Shoaid Munir How can I move it to top for all pages, like global

Comment: No need to move top of all pages, you need to add it in your **ajax add to cart success function**

Comment: @Shoaid Munir, My UI requirement is to move it to top of the pages, as I added the image also. Moving notification at the top is one part of the issue and latency part was another part. So i am asking moving notifications at the top of the pages

Comment: I have updated my answer, please check now

Comment: How can i remove the multiple notifications which appear in stack form one upon another, i want to remove the previous one and replace the current one

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

> ***Method-1 Using Module***

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend**

**requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Theme/js/view/messages':'VendoreName_ModuleName/js/view/messages'
        }
    }
};
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/web/js**

**messages.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },

        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.setConf({path: '/', expires: -1}).set('mage-messages', null);

        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
    });
});
```

> ***Method-2 Using Theme***

**app/design/frontend/your-vendor-name/your-theme-name/Magento_Theme/web/js/view**

**messages.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'underscore',
    'escaper',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, customerData, _, escaper) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: [],
            allowedTags: ['div', 'span', 'b', 'strong', 'i', 'em', 'u', 'a']
        },

        /**
         * Extends Component object by storage observable messages.
         */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = _.unique($.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages'), 'text');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            // Force to clean obsolete messages
            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.setConf({path: '/', expires: -1}).set('mage-messages', null);

        },

        /**
         * Prepare the given message to be rendered as HTML
         *
         * @param {String} message
         * @return {String}
         */
        prepareMessageForHtml: function (message) {
            return escaper.escapeHtml(message, this.allowedTags);
        }
    });
});
```

**Must be run Magento 2 commands after adding the above files**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento s:d:c
php bin/magento c:c
```