# How to move notification message top of the page for all page

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, messages, success-message

I am trying to move all `notification message` on the top below header(or any specific location)

I followed this link but this only achieve top for customer page only

> [Magento 2: Change message location](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/177528/magento-2-change-message-location)

So that means to place `message` at the top (below header) i have to each and every `xml` file of every `module`?

Is there any shorthand for the same, for all pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in default.xml in the below path

> app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

or

> app/design/frontend/vendor/theme-name/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
>
> default.xml will render in all the pages so it's an global declaration.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>                                                     
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="messages" destination="header.container" after='-' />
</body>                                                                  
</page>
```

Not tested try it and let me know.

Comment: Add default.xml in Magento_Theme ?

Comment: updated the answer

Comment: Thanks worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move block for every page you should use "Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml" in your theme-directory

Answer (score 0):

first, create layout file in the theme
layout

```
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="after_body_start">
        <block type="core/template" name="top.messages" template="core/messages/top.phtml" before="-" />
    </reference>
</default>
```

Template: ( app/design/frontend/your_package/your_theme/template/core/messages/top.phtml )

```
<?php $_messageCollection = $this->getMessagesBlock()->getMessageCollection() 
?>

<?php if ($_messageCollection->count()): ?>
<div>
<?php
echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();
$_messageCollection->clear();
?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

please let me know if you have any question

Comment: I will try your approach also